# Count number of workdays

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

[image]

I'm trying to work out a formula:

- `C2` is a date that something is received;
- `I2` is the no of working days to return;
- `L2` is expected return date;
- `N2` is actual completion date;
- `M2` is no of days to complete ( + or - against expected date)

But if no date in `N2` yet , `M` needs to remain blank.

Current formula is:

```
=IF(ISBLANK(N2),0,(N2-L2))
```

But I need it to exclude weekends & bank holidays ( which are listed as `Q2:Q30`)  as currently `M2 is including weekends and holidays in the no of days.

Comment: Are you trying to calculate Number of working days between two, Start & End Date considering Weekend &  Holidays, Could you please upload the  sample data ?

Comment: Have you tried the `WORKDAYS` formula?

Comment: yes, in a different column, but I don't just want to have it to exclude the weekends & holidays, but to also to take in to account what else I need it to do

Comment: If you want a formula that will "take in to account what else I need to do", you need to edit you question to explain what else you want to do.

Comment: "to take into account what else I need to do ", is to show that when N2 is not filled in then M2 does not auto fill, so it doesn't give a false reference , have tried to upload an image to show what I am doing but it wont allow me yet . Also in column M, I have conditional formatting set up so if we are under the expected days its shown as green, and if over the expected days, its shows red .

Comment: As you're a reputation 1 user: If an answer helped you, don't forget to click the grey ☑ to the left of the text, which means "yes, this is THE answer"!

Answer (score 1):

This will give you the idea, if not working exactly as is:

`=IF(ISBLANK(N2),"",networkdays(N2,L2,$Q$2:$Q$999))`

*Not tested, I do not have access to Excel at this time.

NOTE: `;` or `,` to separate arguments depends on your locale, as does the name of this function - use English language locale to avoid problems.*